# Large bitmap not being drawn

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm in the works of a game and I'm loading a large image that is 5120 wide and 116 high. When I try to draw it to the screen using

```
canvas.drawBitmap(land, 0, 0, paint);
```

nothing gets drawn. However when I use a smaller file (512x116) with the same method call, it gets drawn. Is there a  image size limit? My image is 750 KB. Also the max canvas width and height is 8192. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I noticed this in the log: 
Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (20480x464, max=8192x8192)

as if my bitmap is 4 times larger than its actual size. Why would that be?

EDIT 2: Found the issue. Bitmapfactory is returning a larger file because is multiplies the dimensions by my screen density. So the file ends up being too large.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Canvas layout but try using largeHeap = "true" in your Manifest

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help. However I noticed this in the log: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (20480x464, max=8192x8192) As if my bitmap is 4 times larger than its actual size... I'm using a png so maybe it's something to do with file type?

Comment: Found the issue. Bitmapfactory is returning a larger file because is myltiplies the dimensions by my screen density. So the file ends up being too large.